# C#.Net, Get the OLEDB provider version

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I need to Identify the Installed OLEDB provider version. before reading an Excel file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the OleDbEnumerator.GetElements Method . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbenumerator.getelements.aspx to enumarate the drivers. You ask the versions of them maybe this link helps:
http://dotnetref.blogspot.com/2009/04/getting-version-of-oledb-provider.html

Comment: Distinct versions for 32bit and 64bit ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the registry and see if the Jet OLE DB provider is there

The Path is: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines

Then you will have

> Jet
>   4.0
>   Engines
>   Jet 2.0
>   Jet 3.0
>   Jet 4.0

Comment: See the other answer, a managed API call is always better than a custom registry search because when things change, the managed solution would always work while a registry dependent solution might no longer work.

Comment: I agree with you Davide, and the answer from caglar_gonul is what I would recommend, however, the original question didn't specify any constraint so my answer is still valid though not the best :)